# How do I submit an array from the client to a server (ExpressJs) using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I'm working on a web application in which a user can drag and drop div elements, whose content is generated from a database, into their preferred order. I want the user to be able to, when they are finished arranging the divs, submit their list (in order) to the server and store the new order in a table. I'm using AJAX to do this, however I'm not sure if that is necessary/the proper way to do this, since I don't need to asynchronously update the page (I just need to submit the data). I've tried a variety of methods to get my array to the server in a usable format (it needs to be iterable and allow for element locations to be compared). I have tried using JSON.stringify/parse, creating a custom object, simply submitting the array on its own, and so on. Here is my code, the most relevant bits are towards the bottom by the `makeRouteArray` function. Ideally to accomplish this I would like to use just JavaScript (no jQuery). Finally, please excuse my messy code, I'm learning.

```
// get two groups of elements, those that are draggable and those that are drop targets
let draggable = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable]');
let targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-drop-target]');

// div immediately surrounding bus routes
var busList = document.getElementById("bus-list");
const button = document.getElementById("button");


// store the id of the draggable element when drag starts
function handleDragStart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text", this.id); // sets 'text' value to equal the id of this
  this.classList.add("drag-start"); // class for styling the element being dragged, sets opacity
}

function handleDragEnd(e) {
  e.target.classList.remove('drag-start');
}

function handleDragEnterLeave(e) {
  // should provide visual feedback to user?
}

// handles dragover event (moving your source div over the target div element)
// If drop event occurs, the function retrieves the draggable element’s id from the DataTransfer object
function handleOverDrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var draggedId = e.dataTransfer.getData("text"); // retrieves drag data (DOMString) for specified type
  var draggedEl = document.getElementById(draggedId);

  draggedEl.parentNode.insertBefore(draggedEl, this); // inserts element being dragged into list

  var draggedArray = Array.from(draggedEl.parentNode.children); // creates new array which updates current location of each route
  e.target.classList.remove('drag-start'); // sets opacity back to 1

  // if (e.type === "drop") {
  //   // when dropped, update localstorage
  savePage(draggedArray);
  // }
}

// get each full bus-route div in #bus-list with p content as single arr item each

// called when item is dropped
function savePage(dArray) {
  // honestly i can't remember what this does precisely
  // but i can't seem to add to localstorage in the way i want without it
  var arr = Array.prototype.map.call(dArray, function(elem) {
    return elem.outerHTML;
  });
  localStorage.newList = JSON.stringify(arr); // have to stringify the array in order to add it to localstorage
}


// ideally it should just update the order of the bus routes to reflect local storage
// and add classes/ids to the divs etc. (hence using outerHTML)
function makePage() {
  // getting the item from localstorage
  var getData = localStorage.getItem("newList");

  // parsing it back into an array
  var parsedData = JSON.parse(getData);

  // string to hold contents of array so they can be display via innerHTML
  var fullList = "";
  if (localStorage.getItem("newList") === null) {
    return; // maybe this is wrong but if there's nothing in local storage, don't do anything
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < parsedData.length; i++) {
      fullList = fullList + parsedData[i];
    }
    busList.innerHTML = fullList;
    // reassigning targets after calling function in order to re-register event handlers
    draggable = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable]');
    targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-drop-target]');
  }
}



// probably better way to do this
for (let i = 0; i < draggable.length; i++) {
  draggable[i].addEventListener("dragstart", handleDragStart);
  draggable[i].addEventListener("dragend", handleDragEnd);
}

// drop target elements
for (let i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
  targets[i].addEventListener("dragover", handleOverDrop);
  targets[i].addEventListener("drop", handleOverDrop);
  targets[i].addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnterLeave);
  targets[i].addEventListener("dragleave", handleDragEnterLeave);
}


// rolling average: new_average_score = old_average_score * (total_users-1)/total_users + user_route_rank/total_users
// user id, column per route (score)
// session id


// submit button to save changes to db
// when submit is clicked
// get current results from either local storage or from currently ordered + displayed list
// data will be in array format
// do i need AJAX to be able to submit something other than form data to a server?
  // is submitting data in this format (taken from page's HTML ordering) even possible?
// i'd prefer to not use jQuery
// how do i submit an array to the server (express) and then parse (?) it to make it useable?
// so far i have tried JSON.stringify/parse, making a custom object, just submitting array, etc.
// ultimately what i need is a data type that i can loop over and compare positions of stored elements


var makeRouteArray = function() {
  var currentOrderArr = Array.from(busList.children);
  var idData = currentOrderArr.map(function(el) {
    return Number(el.id.slice(2));
  });
  return idData; // not sure if having two return statements like this is okay
};


button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('POST', '/submit', true);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
  request.send(data);
});

makePage();
```

The `makeRouteArray` function is taking ids from an HTML `ul` and stripping them of the first two characters because I only want to use the numbers (the ids are structured as `#r-num`). An array of these numbers is what I would like to submit to the server and if possible, once on the server, return the JSON object to an array.

Thanks!

Comment: So you have stringified the array into JSON data and upon receiving it on the server side you have parsed it into an array... and what has failed..?

Comment: I have tried stringifying the data on the client but when I parse it I get the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: For the line `request.send(data);` I can't find where `data` is defined. Your `content-type` header must be set correctly for the format you're using. Your browser dev tools will show you the request that is being sent (in the Network section), does it contain the data you intended?

Comment: The SyntaxError you mention usually means you're trying to parse an object rather than a string, which suggests you might be trying to parse something that has already been parsed. Try `JSON.parse({})` in your browser console to see that same error. It happens because the object is implicitly converted to the string `'[object Object]'`, which fails to parse when it reaches the letter `o`.